# como llamar un metodo de clase en un boton para que se ejecute ese metodo con django

Tags: django

Resulta que tengo una clase de view y un metodo en esa clase que ejecuta un codigo para descargar un excel , yo necesito ejecutar ese metodo desde un boton en la template como podria hacerlo? probe muchas opciones y no encuentro alguna solucion posible

basicamente lo que necesito es ejecutar ese download_data() en un boton de una template

Clase y metodo

```
class RequestFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 20
    model = Request
    template_name = 'request/filter-request.html'
    form_class = FilterRequestForm
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RequestFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['count_request'] = context['request_list'].count()
        
        if 'form_class' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        
        return context
    

    def download_data(self):
        columns = ['Fecha de Venta', 'Vendedor', 'Ejecutivo', 'Linea a Portar', 'Cliente', 'DNI', 'PORTA/FIBRA', 'Plan Anterior', 'Plan Nuevo', 'Fecha Port Out', 'Provincia', 'Ciudad', 'Alternativo']
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        context = self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.get_queryset())
        date_now = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y--%H-%M')
        desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
        desktop = desktop_path.replace("\\", "/")
        date = desktop + '/' + date_now + '.xlsx'

        for req in context:
            date_of_sale = str(req.date_of_sale)
            seller = req.seller.first_name + ' ' + req.seller.last_name
            customer = req.customer.first_name + ' ' + req.customer.last_name
            new_row = {
                'Fecha de Venta': date_of_sale,
                'Vendedor': seller,
                'Ejecutivo': req.seller.user_in_charge,
                'Linea a Portar': req.mobile_to_carry,
                'Cliente': customer,
                'DNI': req.customer.dni,
                'PORTA/FIBRA': req.product,
                'Plan Anterior': req.get_previus_product_display,
                'Plan Nuevo': req.product_type,
                'Fecha Port Out': req.portation_date,
                'Provincia': req.customer.get_province_display,
                'Ciudad': req.customer.location,
                'Alternativo': req.customer.second_mobile,
            }
            df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(date, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de 2 formas.

**Método 1**

La primera sobrescribiendo el método post de tu vista y con ajax puedes llamar a ese botón por ejemplo seria así.

Vista

```
    from io import BytesIO
    
    class RequestFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
        paginate_by = 20
        model = Request
        template_name = 'request/filter-request.html'
        form_class = FilterRequestForm
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(RequestFilterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    
            context['count_request'] = context['request_list'].count()
    
            if 'form_class' not in context:
                context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
    
            return context
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            data = {}
            action = request.POST['action']
            try:
                if action == 'download_excel':
                    columns = ['Fecha de Venta', 'Vendedor', 'Ejecutivo', 'Linea a Portar', 'Cliente', 'DNI', 'PORTA/FIBRA', 'Plan Anterior', 'Plan Nuevo', 'Fecha Port Out', 'Provincia', 'Ciudad', 'Alternativo']
                    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
                    context = self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.get_queryset())
                    date_now = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y--%H-%M')
                    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
                    desktop = desktop_path.replace("\\", "/")
                    date = desktop + '/' + date_now + '.xlsx'
                    for req in context:
                        date_of_sale = str(req.date_of_sale)
                        seller = req.seller.first_name + ' ' + req.seller.last_name
                        customer = req.customer.first_name + ' ' + req.customer.last_name
                        new_row = {
                            'Fecha de Venta': date_of_sale,
                            'Vendedor': seller,
                            'Ejecutivo': req.seller.user_in_charge,
                            'Linea a Portar': req.mobile_to_carry,
                            'Cliente': customer,
                            'DNI': req.customer.dni,
                            'PORTA/FIBRA': req.product,
                            'Plan Anterior': req.get_previus_product_display,
                            'Plan Nuevo': req.product_type,
                            'Fecha Port Out': req.portation_date,
                            'Provincia': req.customer.get_province_display,
                            'Ciudad': req.customer.location,
                            'Alternativo': req.customer.second_mobile,
                        }
                        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
                    excel_file = BytesIO()
                    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
                    df.to_excel(date, 'sheetname')
                    xlwriter.save()
                    xlwriter.close()
                    excel_file.seek(0)
                    response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(date)
                    return response
                else:
                    data['error'] = 'No ha seleccionado ninguna opción'
            except Exception as e:
                data['error'] = str(e)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Html (El botón para descargar el excel)

```
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-flat btnUpload">
            <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Descargar Excel
        </a>
```

Llamada del ajax por el evento del boton

```
    $(function () {
        $('.btnUpload').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: pathname //pones la url de tu vista,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'action': 'download_excel'},
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function (request) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    var date_now = d.getFullYear() + "_" + d.getMonth() + "_" + d.getDay();
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";
                    const blob = new Blob([request], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
                    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = "download_excel_" + date_now + ".xlsx";
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    message_error(errorThrown + ' ' + textStatus);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**Método 2**

La otra forma es crear una vista que te retorne directamente el excel, seria algo así.

```
Vista

from io import BytesIO
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.base import View

class DowloadExcelView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            columns = ['Fecha de Venta', 'Vendedor', 'Ejecutivo', 'Linea a Portar', 'Cliente', 'DNI', 'PORTA/FIBRA', 'Plan Anterior', 'Plan Nuevo', 'Fecha Port Out', 'Provincia', 'Ciudad', 'Alternativo']
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
            context = self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.get_queryset())
            date_now = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y--%H-%M')
            desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
            desktop = desktop_path.replace("\\", "/")
            date = desktop + '/' + date_now + '.xlsx'
            for req in context:
                date_of_sale = str(req.date_of_sale)
                seller = req.seller.first_name + ' ' + req.seller.last_name
                customer = req.customer.first_name + ' ' + req.customer.last_name
                new_row = {
                    'Fecha de Venta': date_of_sale,
                    'Vendedor': seller,
                    'Ejecutivo': req.seller.user_in_charge,
                    'Linea a Portar': req.mobile_to_carry,
                    'Cliente': customer,
                    'DNI': req.customer.dni,
                    'PORTA/FIBRA': req.product,
                    'Plan Anterior': req.get_previus_product_display,
                    'Plan Nuevo': req.product_type,
                    'Fecha Port Out': req.portation_date,
                    'Provincia': req.customer.get_province_display,
                    'Ciudad': req.customer.location,
                    'Alternativo': req.customer.second_mobile,
                }
                df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
            excel_file = BytesIO()
            xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
            df.to_excel(date, 'sheetname')
            xlwriter.save()
            xlwriter.close()
            excel_file.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(date)
            return response
        except:
            pass
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('URL_SALIDA'))
```

La url

```
    from django.urls import path
    from core.views import DowloadExcelView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('download/excel/', DowloadExcelView.as_view(), name='download_excel'),
]
```

La llamada desde el botón del html

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-flat" target="_blank" href="{% url 'download_excel' %}">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Subir Excel de Productos
    </a>
```